# What is the difference between ACCOUNT and ACCOUNTSTRING in Teradata connection?

Tags: java, teradata

I am connecting to Teradata using jdbc. I have been provided with an ACCOUNT = 'xxx' string that I am supposed to use to privilege my connection . However, I could not find any documentation on the `ACCOUNT` connection parameter. Does Teradata have `ACCOUNT` connection parameter at all ? I could only find the `ACCOUNTSTRING` . They are not the same are they ?

I have been told that the connection string should look like this : 
`DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;ACCOUNT=XXX`

What is the `ACCOUNT` connection string parameter at all  ?

Here is my connection

```
String conStr = "jdbc:teradata://XXX/LOGMECH=LDAP," + "tmode=" + tmode + ","
                + "charset=" + charset + "," + "LOGDATA='authcid=" + user
                + " password=" + pass + "',ACCOUNT=$BDLJ$KFLSMFLMlGSG";
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"); 
Connection conTest = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr);
```

The connection fails. Am I spesifying the `ACCOUNT` parameter correctly ? It works perfectly without that `ACCOUNT . .`

Comment: https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#URL_ACCOUNT  Did the person that gave you that connection string possibly confuse ODBC connection string parameters with JDBC connection string parameters? If you are truly connecting through JDBC, those parameters should be comma seperated, and `DSN`, `UID`, and `PWD` should be changed to the proper JDBC name as outlined in the link here.

Comment: @JNevil That  person doesn't know if I use `jdbc` or `odbc`, he just told me that I could include that `ACCOUNT=xxx` to my connection string (jdbc, or odbc whatever) to prioritize my requests. I included it, but could not see the difference. It looks like it is getting silently ignored. Also, I am confused because I could not find the documentation for `ACCOUNT` connection parameter for teradata connection

Comment: If you are connecting through JDBC then the parameter is called `Account` (See link above), if connecting through ODBC or OLEDB then the parameter is called `AccountString` http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/Connectivity/B035_2509_071A/2509ch02.04.16.html As far as I am aware, they are referring to the same thing, namely which account you will be using for your session.

Comment: An account has a priority assigned to it, but the DBA normally assigns a single account to your userid. If you get multiple accounts your DBA will inform you about that and then you might use the `ACCOUNT`option to switch priority :-)

Comment: Dear experts @dnoeth @JNevill : I updated my question with the actual connection string. The connection fails once I add that `ACCOUNT=..`. Am I using the `ACCOUNT` parameter correctly in the connection string ? Obviously not ;) How should I be using it ? I separated it with a comma . . .

Comment: You can only use an account assigned to your user or profile: `SELECT * FROM dbc.accountInfo
WHERE (UserOrProfile = 'Profile'
  AND USERNAME = PROFILE);` Only if there's no row returned check your user:
`SELECT * FROM dbc.accountInfo
WHERE   (UserOrProfile = 'User'
  AND USERNAME = USER);`

Comment: @dnooeth The first query returned nothing. The second query returned the following : `SPASHA       $ANKM$KHJF       User` . So, the Account name here is completely different from what I have been provided with. Does it mean that I can't use the string they provided to me